# Python IndexError: list index out of range when using a list as an iterable

Tags: python, index-error

Here is the code:

```
import math as m
primeproduct = 5397346292805549782720214077673687806275517530364350655459511599582614290
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181]

def pseudoroot(n):
print(n)
for i in n:
    if n[i] > m.sqrt(primeproduct):
        return n[i-1] #greatest divisor below the root


psrprime = pseudoroot(primes)
```

Running this code gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(pseudoroot(primes))
  File "so.py", line 7, in pseudoroot
    if n[i] > m.sqrt(primeproduct):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Which really doesn't make any sense to me as the i in the for loop is a given index in the list and shouldn't exceed the bounds of that list.

Comment: Where is `primeprod` defined?

Comment: `n[i]` is the index, not the value.  For example, when `i` is `47`, the code is trying to find the value in `primeprod` at index 47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've confused the list *index* with the list *contents*.  `for i in n` means that `i` will take on the values of `n` in sequence: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...

From Python's point of view ... `n` has 42 elements.  As soon as you get to accessing `n[i]` when i is 43, you crash.

Try this:

```
def pseudoroot(n):
    for i, p in enumerate(n):
        if p > m.sqrt(primeproduct):
            return n[i-1] #greatest divisor below the root
```

Do note that this fails in your MCVE, because you don't have enough primes to get to sqrt(primeproduct).

Answer (score 1):

`for i in n` iterates over the *values* not the indicies. If you want the indicies there are a couple ways you could do it, one being `for i, v in enumerate(n)` and then you can use `v` instead of `n[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

> Which really doesn't make any sense to me as the i in the for loop is
>   a given index in the list and shouldn't exceed the bounds of that
>   list.

Not quite. `i` is an *item* in your list, *not* an index.

`for i in n` gives you the *items* in `n`. Not the index. So doing `n[i]` is a bit nonsensical (you're using the *items* as indices). A quick fix is to use `for i in range(len(n))` if you want a c-style index.

More pythonic would be:

```
for before_prime, current_prime in zip(n, n[1:]):
    if current_prime > m.sqrt(primeprod):
        return before_prime #greatest divisor below the root
```